Flutter how to generate list of consecutive double numbers within specific range
How can I generate a list like this in Flutter - double consecutive values with increments of 0.05 between 0.50 and 0.80?
final List<double> List = [0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80];


see List.generate constructor

Yes, I know how to generate a list. But I don't know how to generate a list with those specific parameters. Most resources online deal with generating a list of integers or random numbers.

final List<double> list = List.generate(7, (i) => 0.5 + i * 0.05);

or if you don't wanna have to specify the number of the items in the list while declaring it:
final List<double> list = [for (double i = 0.5; i <= 0.8; i += 0.05) i];

